# Using local SQL Server Database vs Access with Excel Addin

Tags: sql-server, excel, ms-access, mdf, vba

I have an Excel addin which reads/writes from/to a MS access db that is installed on the user's local machine. So each user that installs the addin also needs their own stand alone Access db as well.

I'd like to do this with a SQL server db instead. How can I do that without needing to install SQL server instance on every computer. Is that possible?

I jsut want to add the mdf file on the local/client machine as well as any drivers and then via vba read/write from/to that mdf file

Comment: LocalDB does this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx

Comment: Hm. I suspected but couldn't quitr figure out how to use (or get to) localdb after I installed express. So wasn't sure. I'll check it out in more detail. Thanks